# Replicate SEF URLs Using Article Alias

Tags: sef, seo, alias, navigation, extension-request

I've got a Joomla site that I'm preparing to upgrade to Joomla 4.  I'm currently using the sh404SEF component to create SEF urls that use the article's alias (Ex: example.com/about-us).  I need a another component or method of replicating the current URLs and to continue the pattern for future articles.  Our site is a smaller church site so I'm just looking for a reliable, affordable solution.

Note that the sh404SEF author is taking the opportunity to totally rewrite the component as an SEO component. The current component is not Joomla 4 compatible. They have split off their SEF solution into a separate component but it is not production ready and they don't seem to have enough testers to make it so. Thus I don't want to continue using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Route 66](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/route-66/) should be suitable for your use case. From its description:

> Patterns can include any URL friendly character along with some tokens
> for generating dynamic variables ( like the article's date for example
> ). Here are some examples of URL patterns you can use in Route 66:
>
> - blog/{articleYear}/{articleMonth}/{articleAlias}
> - {categoryAlias}/{articleAlias}
> - {articleAlias}
> - page-{articleId}
> - {categoryPath}/{articleAlias}

So using `{articleAlias}` should work in your case.

[Direct Alias](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/direct-alias/) has a similar function but it seems to be limited to menu items:

> This plugin allows you to switch alias to 'direct' mode and have short
> URL without aliases of parent menu items:
>
> http://site.com/child-menu-item-alias

Comment: Thanks for the info.  It certainly looks like it would do the job and gets good reviews.  I notice in the comments that users are saying it crashes sites that use LESS files in their templates.  I'll have to figure out how to determine if our template uses those.